# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning does not work properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to make a transitioning animation on navigationController's pushes and pops. But it works really weird. Like 1/5 times the `fromViewController` fades out as it should but `toViewController` does not fade in, it just appears. Constraints go weird sometimes too. If I use standard transitioning it is all OK. Here is my transitioning class:

```
class TMFadeAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let toViewController   = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
        let fromViewController   = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
        toViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        fromViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)

        transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(toViewController!.view)


        toViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
            toViewController!.view.alpha = 1.0
            fromViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (finished) in
            toViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
            fromViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, but in my transition context i extract the views not the view controllers using the viewForKey. I doubt that would make a difference, but i guess it's possible that the view controller could have limitations on how you are able to manipulate it's view. I also don't call the begin/end appearance transition.... so i might a little behind on what you are suppose to do for these type of custom animations.

Comment: @A'saDickens as you expected did not make any difference

Comment: Are you able to make a gif of what is happening? I use licecap which is a really simple application. If you can't that is fine. Visuals might just show the answer though XD

Comment: @A'saDickens updated with the gif

Comment: This seems like a problem that might be easy to solve by copying the transition object into a new project and try to make the same thing but with less UI elements. Then you can at least see it working before applying it to your current project.

Comment: Are you popping? it looks like you are switching tabs on a UITabBarViewController

Comment: @A'saDickens No Just pushing. And I am pressing "Submit" button on the bottom and "Continue" on the center

Comment: I have another silly idea that probably wont work! Move `toViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0` above the code that adds the view to the transitionContext.

Comment: @A'saDickens nope) Didn't work either

Comment: My next guess is that the view controllers that are being animated are some how wrong... i Would run different test to see if the alpha for the correct controller is being changed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109059/discussion-between-asa-dickens-and-simon-moshenko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough the problems were solved by putting `toViewController?.view.frame = fromViewController!.view.frame` just after the `toViewController` and `fromViewController` were defined. (Thanks to A'sa Dickens for findinding it out). Here is the final code

```
class TMFadeAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let toViewController   = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
        let fromViewController   = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)

        toViewController?.view.frame = fromViewController!.view.frame

        toViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        fromViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)

        transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(toViewController!.view)


        toViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
            toViewController!.view.alpha = 1.0
            fromViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (finished) in
            toViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
            fromViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```